# What is Jboss standalone.xml? what is the purpose of it?

Tags: jboss, application-server

I know to run the JBoss we need the standalone.xml, but I do not understand the content in the standalone.xml file.

Can someone explain to me what is defined in it with an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the `$JBOSS_HOME/docs/schema` there are several schemas that make up the standalone.xml file.

`standalone.xml` file contains all the information regarding modules used by the JBOSS or wildfly. If you want to know about each and every module then read this http://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/15.0/index.html.

In addditon to this, if you want to learn about the attributes of the sub-systems then access https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossDTDs